# Is Command Handler is just receiving commands from the bus and publish the event?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cqrs, event-sourcing, axon

I am actually new in CQRS and Event Sourcing.

I got confused by Command Handler in Aggregate, when i saw this code :

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Aggregate
public class BankAccountAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private UUID id;
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private String owner;

    @CommandHandler
    public BankAccountAggregate(CreateAccountCommand command){
        AggregateLifecycle.apply(
                new AccountCreatedEvent(
                        command.getAccountId(),
                        command.getInitialBalance(),
                        command.getOwner()
                )
        );
    }
```

that command handler is just publishing an event. as you can see the naming of the object is `AccountCreatedEvent` but it doesn't mean the `Account is created` right?

the account creation is in EventHandler that subscribe `AccountCreatedEvent` :

```
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class BankAccountProjection {

    private final BankAccountRepository repository;
    private final QueryUpdateEmitter updateEmitter;


    @EventHandler
    public void on(AccountCreatedEvent event) throws Exception {
        log.debug("Handling a Bank Account creation command {}", event.getId());
        BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount(
                event.getId(),
                event.getOwner(),
                event.getInitialBalance()
        );
        this.repository.save(bankAccount);
        Boolean isActive =  AggregateLifecycle.isLive();

    }
}
```

What i know is :

- Event is something that has happened.
- Command is something we want to happen.

So why not we put the logic of `Account creation` in the Command Handler? what is the purpose of doing this?

full source code at this [link](https://blog.nebrass.fr/playing-with-cqrs-and-event-sourcing-in-spring-boot-and-axon/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing some concepts. Let's clarify them.

### Event Sourcing

If you implement event sourcing, it means that your source of truth is the events themselves. You store events, not a concrete "state" (an entity). Let's see some pseudo-code:

To create a new account:

```
function createAccount(data) {
  event = new AccountCreatedEvent(data)
  eventStore.save(event)
}
```

To withdraw from an account, for instance:

```
  function withdraw(data) {
    events = eventStore.getEvents(data.accountId)
    account = new Account()
    account.apply(events)
    account.withdraw(data)
    newEvents = account.newEvents
    eventStore.save(newEvents)
  }
```

(This methods would be called by your command handler)

As you see, you generate `account` from its events, instead of read it from a repository. Account class would be something like this:

```
class Account {

  amount = 0
  newEvents = []

  function apply(events) {
    events.forEach(event => {
      if event == AccountCreatedEvent {
        this.amount = event.initialAmount
      } else if (event == WithdrawalApplied) {
        this.amount = this.amount - event.amount
      } // more event types
    })
  }

  function withdraw(data) {
    // here is where you ensure aggregate invariants (business rules)
    if this.amount == 0 {
      throw Error("no money")
    }
    this.amount = this.amount - data.amount
    newEvents.add(new WithdrawalApplied(data))
  }

}
```

So to your question:

> that command handler is just publishing an event. as you can see the
> naming of the object is AccountCreatedEvent but it doesn't mean the
> Account is created right?

The answer is that you should store the event in command handler. And that precisely means the account is created. Then, you can publish the event as your are doing, if needed. Keep reading.

### CQRS

With CQRS you just separate your queries and commands, but this technique can be applied without event sourcing at all.

### Projections

Since your source of truth consists of a bunch of events, when client wants to query an account by ID, for instance, you need to query all the events and build your account from them. This can be slow. So, when using CQRS and event sourcing, to achieve faster reads, you can apply this technique.

Basically, it consists of listen to the events and build a pre-built projection of the aggregate. This projection can be stored in a MongoDB, PostgreSQL or even a file. That's an implementation detail.

The image below illustrates how three techniques (CQRS, Event Sourcing and Projections) work together.

[image]

Comment: So when we store the event in the command handler it means that the Account was created successfully right? but how we can validate those events? something like the Account already exists in the database?

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Of course, you need to validate things. You can query all the events where accountID == newID and if there are any, throw an error.

Comment: https://github.com/AxonIQ/code-samples/tree/master/set-based-validation

Answer (score 2):

> I am actually new in CQRS and Event Sourcing.
> I got confused by Command Handler in Aggregate, when i saw this code

Not your fault - I've been studying CQRS/ES for quite some time now, and I find Nebrass Lamouchi's design to be *alien*.

In reading this essay, I see a number of other red flags; so I'd encourage you to look to other sources if you want to learn the "best practices" associated with these design ideas.

> Is Command Handler is just receiving commands from the bus and publish the event?

Almost; in general, when we talk about the command handler we are usually describing a piece of *application* code that consumes messages off of the queue, and in doing so updates our persistent data store.

So if you were to write out the code long hand, the usual pattern would look like

```
void handle(Command c) {
    root = repo.get(c.accountId())
    root.updateMyself(c)
    repo.save(root)
}
```

If you also wanted to broadcast events at this point, then that too would normally happen here in the application layer

```
void handle(Command c) {
    root = repo.get(c.accountId())
    root.updateMyself(c)
    repo.save(root)

    // In "event sourced" designs, this sort of publish is
    // normally "outside" of the transaction.  When using
    // a relational data store, it might not be.  Tradeoffs
    publish(root.events())
}
```

But we don't see that here because Lamouchi is *also* demonstrating the Axon framework, which reduces the amount of boilerplate code - in effect hiding the plumbing.

Is that a good idea?  Take some time to watch [8 Lines of Code](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/8-lines-code-refactoring/), by Greg Young.